# Parse Package Name from Android Market URI

Tags: java, android, uri

Is there a way to get the package name from an android market uri using Uri.parse()?  I'm looking for a cleaner way than using a scanner on a string such as "market://details?id=com.android.app" and getting everything after the "id=" portion.

Comment: That's the easiest way to do that.

Comment: If there was a MarketUri class that exposed a parsePackageName method, that's pretty much all it would be doing.  Maybe some format checking and what not, but that's pretty much all you need.  If putting that String position/substring code inline doesn't look clean enough to you, make your own helper class with a static method for parsing market uri's and then your code wherever you call this will look clean and intentional